# MongoDB replica set write majority behavior during outage

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have a replica set configured with 3 servers:

1. Primary
2. Secondary
3. Arbiter

For durability I am inserting new documents with w:majority.

What happens if my primary or secondary servers go down? Will my writes still be successful albeit less durable? What happens if the secondary and arbiter nodes go down -- will I still be able to write to the primary using the same w:majority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will my writes still be successful albeit less durable?

No since the majority of configured members is no longer up, plus the Arb is a non data holding node.

#### Edit

Misread the "or" for an "and".

If one goes down then writes will still continue, after an election if the primary goes but as you said they will be less durable due to the Arb being a non data holding node.

> What happens if the secondary and arbiter nodes go down

Again the Primary will initiate an election and step down to a secondry when that election fails.

(You can set the vote settings of the other two to stop this but not sure if that's a good idea)

> will I still be able to write to the primary using the same w:majority?

No only read from the once primary.

Comment: So, in this case I would truly need 3 servers (not just two servers and an arbiter) for any sort of high availability?

Comment: @jckdnk111 really if two of the 3 go down you would probably need to add more members or reconfigure the set

Comment: right, if any two go down I'm definitely in bad shape. However, if I read your answer correctly I'd be in equally bad shape if even 1 data-holding node goes down (i.e. I can no longer write using w:majority).

Comment: @jckdnk111 nah the arb should ack but it won't take the write, so yeah for HA you actually prolly want 3 actual servers

Comment: ok, so then the answer to `Will my writes be successful albeit less durable if either primary OR secondary goes down` is actually `yes`?

Comment: @jckdnk111 yes, wites will still go through if one fails

Comment: @jckdnk111 oh sorry misread, I thought you said your primary and secondary but I see you said or now